# why should we use std::move semantic with unique pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

### Conceptual Question

Say we have simple example like this:

```
 void foo(std::unique_ptr<int> ptr)
 {
    std::cout << *ptr.get() << std::endl;
 }
 int main()
 {
    std::unique_ptr<int> uobj = std::make_unique<int>(4);
    foo(uobj );  // line-(1) Problem ,but Alternative -> foo(std::move(uobj ))
    std::unique_ptr<int> uobjAlt = uobj; // line-(2) Problem ,but Alternative -> std::unique_ptr<int> uobjAlt = std::move(uobj);        
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

We know simply **std::unique_ptr** bound with concept of resource owning by single owner with moving resource among multiple owners while shared_ptr has opposite aspect.
As example shown above, when you look at **line-(1)** & **line-(2)**  you notice that some standard rules are being violated because std::unique_ptr has(deleted) no both copy constructors and copy assignable operators defined, but In order to avoid compilation errors we have to use **std::move** function instead.

### Problem

Why modern C++ compiler cannot automatically generate instructions to move the resource among unique pointers in **line-(1)** and **line-(2)**? because we know unique pointer intentionally design for that. Why should we use std::move explicitly to instruct the machine to move ownership of the resource?

std::unique_ptr nothing but class template.we know that, But situations addressed in line-1 and line -2 having issues while *compiler complain about copying unique_pointers not allowed(deleted functions)*.why we having these kind of errors why c++ standard and compiler vendors cannot override this concept?

Unique Pointer intentionally designed for the purpose of moving resource while passing its ownership, when we pass it as function/constructor argument or assign to another unique pointer, it conceptually should move resource with ownership nothing else, but why we should use std::move to convey compiler to actual move, why don't we have a freedom to call line-(1) and line-(2) as it is? (while intelligent compiler generate automatic move operation among unique pointers for us, unless there is **const or non-const reference** passing).

(Sorry for long description and broken English) Thank you.

Comment: Because it would be too dangerous to make it automatic. Not being automatic enforce you to think about what you are doing... After all, if you design something to have a unique owner, you may want it to be always the same owner and not mistakenly change its ownership just by calling a function.

Comment: And the compiler complains because it tries to implement the specification of the C++ standard.

Comment: Back in the day, this is how `auto_ptr` worked, and it was horrible.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Thanks for the quick reply. But the person who is using it know what concept behind it. He/She knows pass by ref or value differences, then why we should call std::move every time for Unique ptr? situations for std:: container such as vectors acceptatble... but for unique_ptr !!

Comment: When someone pass unique_ptr as argument to a function as value programmer should know that key thing behind it- moving resource and transferring ownership... :)

Comment: If you want to "move" something into a vector, you need to pass an rvalue or use `std::move`. Same here. How can the compiler guess that you want your lvalue `uobj` to be moved from? You still have it after the function call.

Comment: After function call `uobj` holds no resource(owning nothing),therefore if programmer use it `uobj` after function call ,it should crash or access violation something.it's up to the situation ,because `uobj` no longer owns anything valid.

Comment: @macxfadz I totally disagree, languages features and compilers must protect the programmer about mistakes, and that could be a serious mistake... Haven't it happened to you? And more, the code is clear about programmer's intentions.

Comment: The whole point is for the compiler to complain if the programmer tries to make a copy. Semantically a copy happens with the `a = b;` If an object is not copyable then the compiler forces us to deal with that problem rather than moving the value silently away from where it may actually be needed.

Comment: @Galik why It cannot be overridden for the case like std::unique_ptr ? because by concept behind unique_ptr requires that kind of support from compiler side rather than instructing to move  using external party std::move ?  even std::move it nothing but remove-ref and static cast to R-Val

Comment: To make a long story short: Because in C++, compilations errors are preferred over guessed intentions.

Comment: For the same reason that `std::string` doesn't have an implicit conversion to `const char*`, but requires a call to `c_str()`: so that it's harder to accidentally screw up your memory management.

Comment: @PeteBecker you draw a nice point. Thank for the extra tip.

Answer (score 5):

`unique_ptr` is useful to *free memory for you automatically* when `uobj` goes out of scope. That's its job. So, since it has 1 pointer it has to free, it has to be *unique*, and hence its name: *unique_ptr*!

When you do something like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> uobjAlt = uobj;
```

You're issuing a *copy* operation, but, you're not supposed to copy the pointer, because copying means that both objects `uobjAlt` and `uobj` must both be freed, which will directly lead to a segmentation fault and a crash. So, by using `std::move`, you're *moving ownership* from one object to another.

If you want to have multiple pointers to a single object, you should consider using [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: ,problem is, when std::unique_ptr<int> uobjAlt = uobj; compiler analyze this line why it cannot  generate move operation for us rather than looking up for copying ,should not it specialize for unique pointer?
Why compiler see it as copying rather than moving for unique_ptr that's conflict arise at first place..

Comment: @macxfadz Because it's ambiguous and has multiple meanings. In the old days before C++11, there was `auto_ptr`, which exactly allowed that, and it was a catastrophe. Read about `auto_ptr` and how it got deprecated exactly for this reason.

Comment: @macxfadz No, it shouldn't. As pointed out in the comments, that would make it too easy to make mistakes. The idea is that if you have an lvalue, you only move from it by asking for it to be moved explicitly.

Comment: @juanchopanza 
So basic idea is **avoid mistakes** . Thanks for the conveying the basic rule behind it. really appreciated all of your ideas and answers.:D

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with whether the compiler can do this.  It certainly could work that way, and in fact, it did work that way prior to C++11 with `std::auto_ptr<>`.  It was horrible.

```
std::auto_ptr<int> x = std::auto_ptr<int>(new int(5));
std::auto_ptr<int> y = x;
// Now, x is NULL
```

The problem here is that the `=` sign usually means "copy from x to y", but in this case what is happening is "move from x to y, invalidating x in the process".  Yes, if you are a savvy programmer you would understand what is going on here and it wouldn't surprise you, at least not all of the time.  However, in more common situations it would be horribly surprising:

Here's `MyClass.h`:

```
class MyClass {
private:
    std::auto_ptr<Type> my_field;
    ...
};
```

Here's `MyClass.cpp`:

```
void MyClass::Method() {
    SomeFunction(my_field);
    OtherFunction(my_field);
}
```

Here's `Functions.h`:

```
// Which overload, hmm?
void SomeFunction(Type &x);
void SomeFunction(std::auto_ptr<Type> x);

void OtherFunction(const std::auto_ptr<Type> &x);
```

Now you have to look at *three different files* before you can figure out that `my_field` is set to NULL.  With `std::unique_ptr` you only have to look at one:

```
void MyClass::Method() {
    SomeFunction(std::move(my_field));
    OtherFunction(my_field);
}
```

Just looking at this one function I know that it's wrong, I don't have to figure out which overload is being used for `SomeFunction`, and I don't have to know what the type of `my_field` is.  There's definitely a balance that we need to have between making things explicit and implicit.  In this case, the fact that you couldn't explicitly tell the difference between moving and copying a value in C++ was such a problem that rvalue references, `std::move`, `std::unique_ptr`, etc. were added to C++ to clear things up, and they're pretty amazing.

The other reason why `auto_ptr` was so bad is because it interacted poorly with containers.

```
// This was a recipe for disaster
std::vector<std::auto_ptr<Type> > my_vector;
```

In general, many templates worked poorly with `auto_ptr`, not just containers.

Answer (score 2):

If the compiler were allowed to auto-infer move semantics for types such as `std::unique_ptr`, code like this would break:

```
template<typename T> void simple_swap(T& a, T& b) {
    T tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```

The above counts on `tmp` being a *copy* of `a` (because it continues to use `a` as the left-hand side of as assignment operator). There is code in the standard algorithms which actually requires temporary copies of container values. Inferring moves would break them, causing crashes at run-time. This is why `std::auto_ptr` was warned against ever being used in STL containers.

Comment: with your function `simple_swap` if `a`- unitque_ptr and also `b`-unique_ptr,since they are passed as non-const ref type, finally `a` owns resource of `b` and `b` owns resource of `tmp` which previously owns by `a`.what's wrong with that?

Comment: @macxfadz Copy and move semantics are not only defined in terms of `std::unique_ptr`. A moved object must not be used in any way except destruction. In this example the moved object `a` appears on the left-hand side of an assignment operator, which will crash valid C++ objects.

Comment: Even if one allowed further use of moved objects, there are other algorithms that actually rely on the temporary copy to exist in parallel with the original value (e.g. a copy of "pivot" element in quicksort), and would break if a move were suddenly performed where a copy was expected.

Comment: @ user4815162342  yeah transferring ownership with moving resource must to intentionally. I accept algorithms mostly dealt with will be given unexpected results or undefined behavior, but on the other hand the programmer/developer should aware what he is doing with std::move/std::unique_ptr or at least auto_ptr.